# Affiliate link system

Tags: ecommerce

Has anybody implemented an affiliate program system ? If yes, how ?
I saw that Superbig has a plugin in his pipeline, but it's not out yet.

Thanks a lot for your feedback !

Antoine

Answer (score 2):

This probably isn't the answer you need but what features are you actually needing it to do? Affiliate systems can range the gamut from simply dropping a cookie to tracking commissions.

Even a very basic system using coupon codes tracked in Craft Commerce could technically be considered an "affiliate" program. (Coupon codes happen to be relatively reliable since they hold up across devices, cookies etc.)

I've done a bit of this before, when a request comes in that has the UTM or whatever parameters you need, you set a cookie on the request. When someone checks out, you can check for the cookie and set a custom field on the order.

Seeing as Craft is pretty flexible, it's also possible you may also want to consider an out-of-the-box system that works in conjunction with Craft.